# How to use Tampermonkey to spoof system time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tampermonkey

I'm trying to develop a script using Tampermonkey to manipulate the system time in JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to proceed. My goal is to simulate a different date and time than the one displayed on the user's computer, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using Tampermonkey.

I've used the Tampermonkey "fake date" script, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected in the latest firefox.

Specifically, I want to output a fake date in JavaScript, but when I check the system time using new Date(), it still shows the current date and time on the user's computer. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or if there's a better approach to spoofing the system time using Tampermonkey.

Can anyone suggest a solution or offer any guidance on how to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fake Date
// @namespace    fake-date-script
// @version      1
// @description  Set a fake date in your browser globally using Tampermonkey
// @match        http://*/*
// @match        https://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Specify the fake date and time you want to use
    const fakeDate = new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');

    // Override the global Date object with a custom FakeDate class
    class FakeDate extends Date {
        constructor() {
            super();
            return fakeDate;
        }
    }

    window.Date = FakeDate;

})();
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is supposed to be - your above IIFE, with `console.log((new Date()).toISOString())` added after it, gets me `"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"` printed in the console in Chrome and Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/exotpLnr/

Comment: Could your script be loading too late?

Comment: Use `// @run-at document-start` so that your script runs as soon as possible.